# create multi-indexed dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I do not know how to create a multi-indexed df (that has unequal number of 2nd-indices). here is a sample:

```
data = [{'caterpillar': [('Сatérpillar',
    {'fuzz': 0.82,
     'levenshtein': 0.98,
     'jaro_winkler': 0.9192,
     'hamming': 0.98}),
   ('caterpiⅼⅼaʀ',
    {'fuzz': 0.73,
     'levenshtein': 0.97,
     'jaro_winkler': 0.9114,
     'hamming': 0.97}),
   ('cÂteԻpillÂr',
    {'fuzz': 0.73,
     'levenshtein': 0.97,
     'jaro_winkler': 0.881,
     'hamming': 0.97})]},
 {'elementis': [('elEmENtis',
    {'fuzz': 1.0, 'levenshtein': 1.0, 'jaro_winkler': 1.0, 'hamming': 1.0}),
   ('ÊlemĚntis',
    {'fuzz': 0.78,
     'levenshtein': 0.98,
     'jaro_winkler': 0.863,
     'hamming': 0.98}),
   ('еlÈmÈntis',
    {'fuzz': 0.67,
     'levenshtein': 0.97,
     'jaro_winkler': 0.8333,
     'hamming': 0.97})]},
 {'gibson': [('giBᏚon',
    {'fuzz': 0.83,
     'levenshtein': 0.99,
     'jaro_winkler': 0.9319,
     'hamming': 0.99}),
   ('ɡibsoN',
    {'fuzz': 0.83,
     'levenshtein': 0.99,
     'jaro_winkler': 0.9206,
     'hamming': 0.99}),
   ('giЬႽon',
    {'fuzz': 0.67,
     'levenshtein': 0.98,
     'jaro_winkler': 0.84,
     'hamming': 0.98}),
   ('glbsՕn',
    {'fuzz': 0.67,
     'levenshtein': 0.98,
     'jaro_winkler': 0.8333,
     'hamming': 0.98})]}]
```

I want a df like this (note: 'Other Name' has differing number of values for each 'Orig Name':

```
Orig Name| Other Name| fuzz| levenstein| Jaro-Winkler| Hamming
------------------------------------------------------------------------
caterpillar  Сatérpillar  0.82   0.98.      0.9192        0.98
             caterpiⅼⅼaʀ  0.73   0.97       0.9114        0.97
             cÂteԻpillÂr  0.73   0.97       0.881         0.97
gibson       giBᏚon       0.83.  0.99       0.9319        0.99
             ɡibsoN       0.83   0.99.      0.9206        0.99
             giЬႽon       0.67.  0.98       0.84          0.98
             glbsՕn       0.67.  0.98.      0.8333        0.98
elementis .........
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried :

```
orig_name_list = [x for d in data for x, v in d.items()]
value_list = [v for d in data for x, v in d.items()]
other_names = [tup[0] for tup_list in value_list for tup in tup_list]
algos = ['fuzz', 'levenshtein', 'jaro_winkler', 'hamming']
```

Not sure how to proceed from there. Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try concat:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([x[1]]).assign(OrigName=k, OtherName=x[0]) 
               for df in data for k,d in df.items() for x in d])
```

Output:

```
   fuzz  levenshtein  jaro_winkler  hamming     OrigName    OtherName
0  0.82         0.98        0.9192     0.98  caterpillar  Сatérpillar
0  0.73         0.97        0.9114     0.97  caterpillar  caterpiⅼⅼaʀ
0  0.73         0.97        0.8810     0.97  caterpillar  cÂteԻpillÂr
0  1.00         1.00        1.0000     1.00    elementis    elEmENtis
0  0.78         0.98        0.8630     0.98    elementis    ÊlemĚntis
0  0.67         0.97        0.8333     0.97    elementis    еlÈmÈntis
0  0.83         0.99        0.9319     0.99       gibson       giBᏚon
0  0.83         0.99        0.9206     0.99       gibson       ɡibsoN
0  0.67         0.98        0.8400     0.98       gibson       giЬႽon
0  0.67         0.98        0.8333     0.98       gibson       glbsՕn
```

Comment: Nice list comprehension! And to match to output exactly, let's say you set that to `new_data`, then `new_data=new_data.set_index(['OrigName','OtherName'])`, but that is the easy part.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to reformat your data for json record consumption via the `pd.json_normalize` function. Your json is currently not formatted correctly to be stored into a dataframe easily:

```
new_data = []
for entry in data:
    new_entry = {}
    for name, matches in entry.items():
        new_entry["name"] = name
        new_entry["matches"] = []
        for match in matches:
            match[1]["match"] = match[0]
            new_entry["matches"].append(match[1])
    new_data.append(new_entry)


df = pd.json_normalize(new_data, "matches", ["name"]).set_index(["name", "match"])

print(df)
                         fuzz  levenshtein  jaro_winkler  hamming
name        match                                                
caterpillar Сatérpillar  0.82         0.98        0.9192     0.98
            caterpiⅼⅼaʀ   0.73         0.97        0.9114     0.97
            cÂteԻpillÂr  0.73         0.97        0.8810     0.97
elementis   elEmENtis    1.00         1.00        1.0000     1.00
            ÊlemĚntis    0.78         0.98        0.8630     0.98
            еlÈmÈntis    0.67         0.97        0.8333     0.97
gibson      giBᏚon       0.83         0.99        0.9319     0.99
            ɡibsoN       0.83         0.99        0.9206     0.99
            giЬႽon       0.67         0.98        0.8400     0.98
            glbsՕn       0.67         0.98        0.8333     0.98
```